# How to Use Gradient Coloring exactly 45 degree in xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to colour my image by dividing it 45 degrees, below is the code I have implemented but I am getting as attached image. Can any tell me how to divide it exactly?

[image]

```java
public class MultiView : View   
{  
    Bitmap bitmap;  
    int[] colorCodes;  
    float[] positions;    

    public MultiView(Context context, Bitmap _bitmap,int[]colors,float[] _positions) : base(context)  
    {  
        colorCodes = new int[] { Color.Red,Color.Purple};  
        bitmap = _bitmap;  
        positions = _positions ;  
        this.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);    
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas).  
    {  
        base.Draw(canvas);  
        Paint paint = new Paint();  
        //Shader shader = new LinearGradient(startX, startY, EndX, EndY, colorCodes, positions, Shader.TileMode.Mirror);  
        Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, bitmap.Width,0,bitmap.Height,colorCodes,positions,Shader.TileMode.Mirror);  
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  
        matrix.SetRotate(45);  
        shader.SetLocalMatrix(matrix);  
        paint.SetShader(shader);  
        canvas.DrawRect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, paint);                                          
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the pivot at the place where you want to rotate it. In this case:

```
matrix.SetRotate(45, bitmap.Width / 2, bitmap.Height / 2);
```

EDIT:
If you want to divide it evenly through the corners:

```
var degreesRot = Math.Atan2(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height) / Math.PI * 180;
matrix.SetRotate(degreesRot, bitmap.Width / 2, bitmap.Height / 2);
```

Comment: it is not working for me ,it is also dividing, but not exactly at the diagonal points

Comment: What do you mean by dividing? Do you want to draw the line from the top left to the bottom right?

Comment: Instead of 45, use `Math.Atan2(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height) / Math.PI * 180`